# Where to place a database query in model? (Symfony framework)

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm new to PHP programing and Symfony. English isn't my native language so sorry if it sounds strange how I write...

I have two entities: **Article** and **Category**, where each Article has a Category. And I need to show how many articles I have for a given category:

**Category**    ------------------ **N°**

Vehicles    -------------------- 4

Electronics ---------------- 20

Food ----------------------- 15

Furniture   ------------------ 8

With Doctrine I've made the CRUD files for both entities.

```
 php app/console doctrine:generate:crud
```

Like I said, the problem is that I want to show a table with properties of a Category (name, description, etc) and how many articles of it are in the inventory.

The SQL query is very simple:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM Articles a WHERE a.id_category = $id_category
```

Where to put that?! I'm very confused and don't want to brake best practice rules.
Doctrine generated lots of files: ArticleController.php, ArticleType.php (Form), and all the .twig for the views. Same for Category.

Comment: Incidentally, no need to apologize for your English, it's better than that of many native speakers whose writing I've seen.

Comment: IMO start to coding with Symfony2 without read carefully all the documentation (and without a little knowledge of PHP and OOP, or of other language Object Oriented like Java or C) is a very bad approach (in general) and a waste of time because at some point you'll have to start from scratch by following the right steps... that means start reading the docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the spirit of giving a direct answer to your question: what you need is a [custom Doctrine Repository](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#custom-repository-classes), in this case an `ArticleRepository`.

e.g.
**ArticleRepository.php**

```
namespace ACME\DemoBundle\Article;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class ArticleRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function countForCategory($id)
    {
        $result= $this->createQueryBuilder('a')
            ->join('a.category', 'c')
            ->where('c.category_id = :id')
            ->setParameter('id', $id)
            ->select('count(a')
            ->getQuery()
            ->getSingleScalarResult();

        return $result;
    }
}
```

And then you set your Article entity to use that ArticleRepository

**Article.php**

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="article")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="ACME\DemoBundle\Entity\ArticleRepository")
 */
class Article
{
/// etc...
```

You can then get the Repository for the Entity in e.g. your Controller (although as suggested elsewhere you can hide this away in some kind of service to avoid filling your Controller with business logic; it just needs to be reachable somehow from inside your Controller), and run the query:

**ArticleController**

```
class ArticleController extends Controller
{
    public function countAction($id)
    {

        $articleRepo = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('DemoBundle:Article');

        $count = $articleRepo->countForCategory();
        //etc...
```

NB If you really want exactly the output in your example, it may be more efficient to do one query for the whole table, probably in a CategoryRepository, performing a count and grouping by Category.  The query would return an array containing Category name and count.

Answer (score 1):

When using Symfony2 + Doctrine2,

1. don't think (so much) about the database. Think of persistent data objects, so called *entities*, and let Doctrine handle them. Spend some time on cleanly defining the relations between those objects, though.
2. forget about the term “MVC”. MVC is a rather abstract concept, things are more complex in reality. Fabian (lead dev of SF) has a nice write-up about this topic: http://fabien.potencier.org/article/49/what-is-symfony2

If you wonder where to put what in your Symfony bundles, read this Cookbook article: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/best_practices.html

Comment: +1 but, let's talk about Repository also and your answer will be complete :)

Comment: Ok, what do you want to know? I'll add it in the post.

Answer (score 0):

Create a CategoryManager class in your service layer, and handle any business logic there. You can pass the router to it through dependency injection.

For your example, CategoryManager would have a getUrl(Article $article) method which would use the router instance (that you either injected through __construct or a separate setter method) to generate the Url based on properties of $article, and return it.

This method will ensure that your business logic doesn't pollute the view or controller layers.

Check this link [Services Symfony](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I think that is a bit out of my knowledge. Im not familiar with that Service Layer. Never thought that it would be so complicated. Maybe a bit overkill for such a simple requeriment?